# Adapted and right continuous process that is not locally bounded.

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes

A process $X$ is locally bounded if there exists a sequence of stopping times $\tau_n$ increasing to infinity such that the stopped processes $1_{\{\tau_n > 0\}}X^{\tau_n}$ are each uniformly bounded. Then, any continuous process is locally bounded if we take $\tau_n=\inf\{t:|X_t|\geq n\}$.

Similarly, any Cadlag process is locally bounded. Can we extend the result to a right-continuous process? Why cannot we use $\tau_n$ as in the continuous case?